# Error in show function while inserting elements in a stack

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I am writing code to push and pop elements in a stack but my show function is not working correctly and is printing memory addresses inifinitely

```
typedef struct Stack
 {
   int info;
   struct Stack *next;
 }
  stack;
  stack *head;
```

//x the element to be inserted

```
  void push(int x)
  {
     stack *ptr;
     stack *ptr1;
```

//allocating the size

```
     ptr=(stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
     ptr->info=x;
     if(head==NULL)
      {
       ptr->next=NULL;
       head=ptr;
      }
     else
      {
      ptr1=head;
      while(ptr1->next!=NULL)
      {
      ptr1=ptr1->next;
      }
      ptr1->next=ptr;
      ptr->next=NULL;
     }
   }
```

//show function to print the output

```
   void show()
    {
    stack *ptr=head;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
      {
      printf("%d\n",ptr->info);
      ptr=ptr->next;
  }

} 
  void pop()
  {
    stack *ptr=head;
    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
     {
     ptr=ptr->next;
     }
     free(ptr);
   }
```

Comment: You should see the function that adds elements to the stack.:)

Comment: I just added the push function

Comment: Your code seems ok. Post the code where both routines are used/colled. A little thing: don't cast the malloc return.

Comment: whether the declaration of head in global or local?

Comment: it is global let me post the whole code

Comment: (This isn't directly related to your problem) Your push doesn't comply with the canonical definition of stack. Push should add elements at head and you're adding at the bottom.

Comment: plus you don't show the whole stack you show the top element only.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://ideone.com/m6JPHH , where is the problem?

Comment: you reviewed wrong code

Comment: I just copy pasted this code you provided here and added a main function.